# What is a "bad post"? and how many of them can I have before I am banned?

Tags: discussion

I don't want to get banned, how can I prevent a bad post?

Comment: Closely related (maybe even duplicates): https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6116 https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5951

Comment: if you are not actively intending to get banned or behave offensively, your chances of being banned are rather slim ;)

Comment: Also related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9698/50583

Comment: Should I delete this question? I found out that this is in risk of being a duplicate.